# Vertex object doesn't show up (legacy OpenGL 1.2)

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-1.x

So I got the OpenGL Redbook 3e and am currently on chapter 2 (newer OpenGL seems too difficult for beginners to graphics programming). I copied a code snippet from the book (I added the initialization code and drawing code) and I've tried each of the options for rendering vertex arrays (`glDrawElements`, `glDrawRangeElements`, and `gDrawArrays`). For this example I decided to go with glDrawArrays because it seemed to be the most straightforward. As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with this code because it compiles and runs. However, no polygon is drawn. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I feel like I'm either making an incredibly silly error or am missing something fundamental.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

void display() {
    static GLint vertices[] = { 25, 25,
                    100, 325, 
                    175, 25,
                    175, 325,
                    250, 25,
                    325, 325 };

    static GLfloat colors[] = { 1.0, 0.2, 0.2,
                    0.2, 0.2, 1.0,
                    0.8, 1.0, 0.2,
                    0.75, 0.75, 0.75,
                    0.35, 0.35, 0.35,
                    0.5, 0.5, 0.5 };
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(GLint));
    
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: user253751: Looks like the problem I had was with glOrtho. That makes sense. I will this in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your vertices are so far out of the clipping planes.

`glOrtho` is usually setup using pixel coordinates (but that is not required) see [ref](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml).

You probably want

```
glOrtho(0.0, 512.0, 0.0, 512.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: understanding glOrtho has been one of the things on my list to learn. thanks.

Comment: @testaccoun0987 No problem, [This](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) is a really good tutorial about coordinate systems used in OpenGL.

Comment: @testaccoun0987 glOrtho is basically glScalef and glTranslatef. But instead of telling it how much to scale and translate, you tell it what coordinates you'd like the screen edges to be.